# Parse handlebar template like syntax with javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I would like to make a realtime template engine with handlebar like syntax in JavaScript. I have this template code and i want to slice everything (get tag names and attributes separate by spaces, the content of the tag, etc.)

```
{{#component index}}
    {{#if user.connected}}
        <p>connected as {{user.pseudo}}</p>
    {{/if}}
{{/component}}

{{#component index2}}
{{/component}}
```

I want to make a lexer, is anyone know tutorials or tools?

Comment: The first thing you have to do is create a [grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) for the parser, then you have to classify the grammar according to the [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). Then you have to write the parser or more commonly use a [parser generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators) such as [Jison](http://zaa.ch/jison/). Since your question is too general I do not think you will get a specific answer, only hints and guidelines.

Comment: As you are new to StackOverflow please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Without looking at this in detail, seeing nested delimiters, e.g. `{ }` is a red flag that typically means using a regular language, e.g. regex, will not be possible. Most likely you will have a [context free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar).

Comment: should i separate HTML of my template language or make it a string ? is there any tools for context free grammar

Comment: StackOverflow is not a discuss board, and carrying out long discussions in the comments is discouraged. You need to ask specific questions as a question and not turn your question into a discussion. Seriously, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Don't expect answers to questions in comments that are a discussion, even from me. With regards to `should i separate HTML of my template language or make it a string ?` I don't have enough info to answer, and won't answer as it will be a discussion. :)